# How can I prevent commas surrounded by quotation marks from triggering a new element in this IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, linq

I am loading in CSV data like this:

```
var csvData = File.ReadAllLines(filePath)
               .Skip(1)
               .Select(x => x.Split(','))
               .Select(x => new FormattedRow
               {
                   IDOrderAlpha = x[0],
                   IDOrder = x[1],
                   AddressCompany = x[2],
                   Address1 = x[3],
                   Address2 = x[4],
                   AddressCity = x[5],
                   AddressState = x[6],
                   AddressZip = x[7],
                   AddressCountry = x[8],
                   ShipMethod = x[9],
                   ContactEmail = x[10],
                   ContactName = x[11],
                   ServiceRep = x[12],
                   CustomerPuchaseOrder = x[13]
               });
```

Each element in this CSV is surrounded by commas, e.g.:

```
"18000","18000","Example, LLC", ...
```

How can I prevent this file reader from reading "Example, LLC" as 2 columns?

Comment: The easy answer is don't do it yourself.  This is a solved problem, one with quite a few nuances.  There are already plenty of CSV readers out there, just use one of them.

Comment: CSV parsing is a solved problem -- you're reinventing the wheel. Why not use one of the dozens of available CSV parsing libraries?

Comment: @Servy Cool, are there any you recommend?

Comment: use linqtocsv: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25133/LINQ-to-CSV-library

Comment: @anwyatt [Ask here](https://www.google.com/)

Comment: I'll echo everyone else and say there is no need to do this yourself, but if you insist on doing it yourself, the "easy" (yet prone to failing on edge cases) is to replace `x.Split(',') with a call to [Regex.Split()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8yttk7sy(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Try out the CsvHelper NuGet package.